# What microphone can I attach via the 3.5mm audio jack @ Samsung Galaxy S4?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, audio-recording

I need to attach an external microphone to my phone.
Can I do this via the 3.5mm jack on my `Samsung Galaxy S4`? What kind of microphone would it be?

Answer (score 1):

I found this 3.5mm jack noise-reducing microphone on YouTube: [Galaxy Samsung S4 External Mic for mobile phone](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fWjDl0e8YjQ) and [here](http://www.ebay.com/itm/SENSITIVE-TIE-CLIP-LAPEL-LAVALIER-MICROPHONE-for-SAMSUNG-GALAXY-SMARTPHONES-/280916075048?pt=UK_Music_Instruments_Microphones_MJ&var=&hash=item4167e72228) is the mic quoted on eBay. I plan to test it and return some feedback here. I hope it will serve me well enough for the footage I need to create - some homemade lectures.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that, but you'll need an adapter: the 3.5 mm jack on the phone is for a headset (with earphones and a mic), so it's not made to take a standard mic input. You need to find an adapter that's for plugging a microphone into Samsung phones. It might be tricky to find, but they're inexpensive.

Once you have the adapter, any microphone with a 3.5 mm connector will do. Stage mics requiring XLR and 12 V "phantom power" won't work: you'd need an extra device to supply power to the mic, such as a mixing desk with a 3.5 mm output.

Comment: I don't need a stage mic, but any mic that can clear noise very well. I prefer it to be standalone, is this possible?

Comment: As I say, any mic with a 3.5 mm connector will do. I can't recommend a particular one to you: that's way outside the scope of the site.